# Facebook deleting gaming applications

Tags: facebook, sdk

many game apps I have on Facebook are being deleted, and when I ask the facebook support, the answer is always the same:

"We've disabled your app for creating a negative experience on Facebook in Violation of our policies (https://developers.facebook.com/policy). Common violations include Sending Out excessive requests or notifications, auto-posting without consent, and pre-filling content.

We regret That We will not be able to restore your app. This is the final decision. "

I suspect it is something related to "activity log" because whenever the user enters the application, the message in the activity log: "The user playing game ...", or the user "the user is playing"

The code in facebook I am using is this:

```
    <?php
    // appsource
    require_once 'facebook.php';

    require_once 'appinclude.php';
        if (isset($_GET['code'])){
            header("Location: " . $canvasPage);
            exit;
        }

    $fb = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $appid,
        'secret' => $appsecret,
        'cookie' => true
    ));

    $me = null;
     $user = $fb->getUser();

    if($user) {
        try {
            $me = $fb->api('/me');
        } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
        }
    }

    if($me) {}
    else {

        $loginUrl = $fb->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope' => ''
        ));
            echo "
            <script type='text/javascript'>
            window.top.location.href = '$loginUrl';
            </script>
        ";  
        exit;
    }


    if(isset($_GET['signed_request'])) {
        $fb_args = "signed_request=" . $_REQUEST['signed_request'];
    }


    include 'spinc.php';


    function ae_detect_ie(){
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) &&
        (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false))
                return true;    
        else        
            return false;}


    ?>
<html xmlns:fb="//ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content='IE=edge' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
<title>TITLE APP</title>
</script>
</head>
<body><div id="all">
<h1>NAME APP</h1>


<!--Resize Iframe-->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
appId  : '<?=$appid?>',
status : true, // check login status
cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
});
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
</script>
<!-- End Resize Iframe-->


<div id="likebutton"><iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2FXXXAPPNAMEXXX%2F&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35&amp;appId=XXXAPPIDXXX" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe> </div>


<center><object width="750" height="500">
                        <param value="XXXXXXX.swf" name="movie">
                        <param name="allownetworking" value="internal" />
                        <param name="bgcolor" value="#336699" />
                        <param NAME="wmode" value="opaque">
                        <param NAME="quality" value="high">
                        <param name="salign" value="c">
                        <param name="scale" value="exactfit">
                        <embed salign="c" scale="exactfit" width="750" height="550" src="XXXXXXXXXXX.swf" bgcolor="#336699" allownetworking="internal" wmode="opaque" allowfullscreen="true" quality="high">
                        </embed>
                    </object>
 </center>


 </div>

</body></html>
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Since that code doesn’t do anything but logging the user in and requesting their basic profile to confirm they logged in, I hardly doubt that _this_ is what gets your apps blocked – but I also doubt that this is all your app does, right? A pure login is hardly what I would call a “game” …

Comment: Hello, after the php code comes the html code.
Within this html code I write the following code:http://pastebin.com/jbHr6xEi

Comment: The messages you see in activity log are automatically generated by Facebook itself, and it would make no sense that they ban your app based on those. I am pretty sure that your “suspicion” in that regard is just plain wrong.

Comment: I realized that in large access applications on the facebook app center, the actions are not recorded in the "activity log" user.
I believe this may be something to do with my php code.
Is there any way to prevent the actions in my application remain registered in "activity log" user?

Comment: The “Social Discovery” setting (under Settings->Advanced) controls if Facebook automatically publishes such messages or not. But again, it is totally unlikely that your apps got banned for those.

Comment: OK, I got it! thanks for your help! ;)